# How can I set an object key to a constant variable?

Tags: reactjs, object

refer to code below:

```
const item = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
    console.log(data[key].item);
});
console.log("item -----> ", item)

const detail = () => {
    switch(item) {

      case "1":   return <CardDetailA />;
      case "2":   return <CardDetailB />;

      default:      return <CardDetailA />
    }
  }
```

My data file

```
export default [
  
  {
    item: 1,
    pics: [
      './CardImg/img1.jpg',
    ],
    name: "Abby",
    age: 23,
     distance: "2 miles away",
    text:
       "On the first date I will carve our initials in a tree. It's the most romantic way to let you know I have a knife."
},

  {
    item: 2,
    pics: [
      './CardImg/img2.jpg',
    ],
    name: "Jane",
    age: 22,
    distance: "2 miles away",
    text:
      "On the first date I will carve our initials in a tree. It's the most romantic way to let you know I have a knife."
  },
];
```

and I got the response like this

[image]

I need to make a switch case to return the different value according to the item number.
Any solution to make it work?

Comment: there's no return value on your map function that's why its undefined

Answer (score 0):

- When using `Array.map`, you need to return value on callback. On your code

```
const item = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
    console.log(data[key].item);
});
```

You have only printed the item value on console and have returned nothing so item has `undefined` values.

- And `data` is `array`, not object with `key:value`, so no need to get keys using `Object.keys`. It's enough to use `Array.map` only.

```js
const data = [
  {
    item: 1,
    pics: [
      './CardImg/img1.jpg',
    ],
    name: "Abby",
    age: 23,
    distance: "2 miles away",
    text: "On the first date I will carve our initials in a tree. It's the most romantic way to let you know I have a knife."
  },
  {
    item: 2,
    pics: [
      './CardImg/img2.jpg',
    ],
    name: "Jane",
    age: 22,
    distance: "2 miles away",
    text: "On the first date I will carve our initials in a tree. It's the most romantic way to let you know I have a knife."
  },
];

const item = data.map(({ item }) => item);
console.log("item -----> ", item)

const detail = () => {
  switch(item) {
    case "1":   return '<CardDetailA />';
    case "2":   return '<CardDetailB />';
    default:      return '<CardDetailA />';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
const items = data.map(key => key.item); //return the items array
console.log("items -----> ", items)
```

Invoke **detail method** for each item (based on your usecase)

```
const detail = (item) => {
    switch(item) {

     case "1": return <CardDetailA />; //This line is not needed as default case is present
     case "2":   return <CardDetailB />;

      default:      return <CardDetailA />
    }
  }
```